# Why is my form giving me this error "could not be changed because the data didn't validate."?

Tags: django, django-forms

Why is my form giving me this error "could not be changed because the data didn't validate."?
I am using formset_factory to allow users to edit their information. I checked that when a user leaves a field blank I get the error above. What I want to happen is for django to tell the user what the error is instead of a debug error.

model:

```
class signedup(models.Model):
   dancer_1_fname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   dancer_1_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   dancer_1_email = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   dancer_1_city = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   dancer_1_country = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   dancer_1_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 14)
```

View:

```
   person = modelformset_factory(signedup , form=editcartform, extra = 0, can_delete=True)
   form = person(queryset=signedup.objects.filter(sessionid = session))

   if request.method == 'POST':

       form = person(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid:
          dancer = form.save()
   return render_to_response("editcart.html",locals(),context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and template just renders the form like so `{{form}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `()` to the end of form.is_valid, like so `if form.is_valid()`.

Comment: Seriously, thank you. After everything I tried, I couldn't figure that out.